# Frechet derivative

Tags: calculus, derivatives, partial-derivative, calculus-of-variations, frechet-derivative

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, define by $F:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a functional, $F_u,F_v$ be Frechet derivative of $F$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ variables. We show that $F$ is Frechet differentiable.

We have

> > \begin{align}
> > P&=\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h-F_v\left(u,v\right)l \Vert \\ 
> > &= \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h+F\left(u,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v\right)-F_v\left(u,v\right)l \Vert \\
> > &\leq \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert +\Vert F\left(u,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v\right)-F_v\left(u,v\right)l \Vert \\
> > &\leq \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert  +\epsilon\Vert l\Vert
> > \end{align}
> >     We need to show that 
> >     $$\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert  \leq \epsilon' \Vert h\Vert \quad ???$$

It follows that $F$ admits $F'\left(u,v\right)=F_u\left(u,v\right)h+F_v\left(u,v\right)l$ is the Frechet derivative.
However, we only have that

> >
>   $$\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h \Vert  \leq \epsilon'' \Vert h\Vert \quad ???$$

Comment: Note that, Here F enjoys Linearity, so use that. This claim does not hold for an arbitrarily function.

Comment: I cannot understand what you mean! Can you show me?

Comment: As in the finite-dimensional case, you need some continuity of the partial derivatives.

Comment: this is my proof https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254666/a-proof-on-frechet-derivative can you read it and give me some advice?

Answer (score 2):

$F$ is functional which means $F$ is linear, therefor in argument (5th line) rewrite

$$F(u+h,v+l) = F(u+h,v) +F(0,l)  $$ and $$ F(u,v+l) = F(u,v) +F(0,l) $$

then cancel out like terms and then considering $F$ is differentiable in first argument, you are done !

For general functions it is easy to provide an example in which $F: R \times R \rightarrow R$  has partial derivatives but not differentiable.

Comment: This is really wrong: functional is not equivalent to linear functional!

Comment: in some text books, they define functional as a Linear function! otherwise, for this question we can find a very simple counter example, that's why in solution I pointed out  counter examples....

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2254666/a-proof-on-frechet-derivative