# A proof on Frechet derivative!

Tags: calculus, derivatives, calculus-of-variations, nonlinear-analysis, frechet-derivative

Let $X,Y$ be Banach spaces, define by $F:X\times Y \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a functional, $F_u,F_v$ be Frechet derivative of $F$ with respect to $u$ and $v$ variables. We show that $F$ is Frechet differentiable.

We have

> > \begin{align}
> > P&=\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h-F_v\left(u,v\right)l \Vert \\ 
> > &= \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h+F\left(u,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v\right)-F_v\left(u,v\right)l \Vert \\
> > &\leq \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert +\Vert F\left(u,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v\right)-F_v\left(u,v\right)l \Vert \\
> > &\leq \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert  +\epsilon\Vert l\Vert
> > \end{align}
> >     We need to show that 
> >     $$\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert  \leq \epsilon' \Vert h\Vert \quad ???$$

It follows that $F$ admits $F'\left(u,v\right)=F_u\left(u,v\right)h+F_v\left(u,v\right)l$ is the Frechet derivative. Besides, we have that

> >
>   $$\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h \Vert  \leq \epsilon'' \Vert h\Vert \quad $$
>   Therefore, 
>   \begin{align}
> Q&=\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)h \Vert \\
>  &=\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h +F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h -F_u\left(u,v\right)h  \Vert \\
> &\leq \Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h \Vert+\Vert F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h -F_u\left(u,v\right)h  \Vert \\
> &\leq \epsilon''\Vert h\Vert +\Vert F_u\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)\Vert \Vert h  \Vert 
> \end{align}
>   On the other hand, since $F_u$ is continuous with respect to $v$ variable it follows that for every $\epsilon''' >0$ there exists a $\delta >0$ such that $\Vert F_u\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)\Vert <\epsilon'''$ for all $\Vert \left(h,l \right) \Vert < \delta.$

Therefore, $$Q \leq \left(\epsilon'' +\epsilon'''\right) \Vert h\Vert.$$

By Cauchy-Schwarz's inequality It leads to that 
\begin{align}
P&\leq \epsilon'\Vert h\Vert+\epsilon \Vert l\Vert , \quad \epsilon'=\left(\epsilon'' +\epsilon'''\right) \\
&\leq \sqrt{{\epsilon'}^2+{\epsilon}^2}\sqrt{\Vert h\Vert^2 + \Vert l \Vert^2}\\
&= \sqrt{2}\epsilon\Vert \left(h,l\right)\Vert, \quad \epsilon=\epsilon'
\end{align}

Consequently, $F$ is Frechet differentiable!

Can you tell me whether or not there is any mistake in this proof?

Comment: There is a mistake. There are partially differentiable $F \colon \mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}$ that aren't differentiable. Have you omitted an assumption that the partial Fréchet derivatives $F_u$ and $F_v$ are continuous?

Comment: yes! In the proof, I used the property that $F_u$ is continuous! But I cannot see where to use the property that $F_v$ is continuous!
Can you show me?

Comment: It seems to me that only the continuity of one of the partial derivatives suffices, provided that the other exists at every point.

Comment: You mean that if one of the partial derivatives is continuous then so is other?

Comment: can you show that?

Answer (score 0):

There are two mistakes in this proof, that can be resolved by imposing the assumption of continuity on both  $F_u$ and $F_v$.

First in
$$\Vert F\left(u+h,v+l\right)-F\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h \Vert  \leq \epsilon'' \Vert h\Vert \quad$$

Here $\delta$ depends on $l$. we know $u,v$ are fix but not $l$ ! as $l$ gets small $\delta $ may get small too.

Second, Absolutely $F_u$ is not linear (necessarily) nor continuous!

Comment: why $\epsilon''$ depends on $l$? Since $F$ is differentiable with respect to $u$ variable, and the differentiability is not dependent on $v.$ So $F$ is partially differentiable with respect to $u$ at $\left(u,v+l\right)$ for all $l$

Comment: $F_u$ is not linear of course, but $F_u\left(u,v\right)$ is linear which is used in the proof.

Comment: $F_u\left(u,v\right)$ is continuous with respect to $v$ variable, when $u$ is fixed!

Comment: There is no doubt about differentiability, My concern is that in epsilon- definition of differentiability, $\epsilon$  does depend on point, So for two points $(u,v)$ , and $(u,v+l)$ you get two different $\epsilon$.

why $F_u$ is continuous in $v-$ argument?
Where did you use linearity of $F_u (u,v)$ ?

Comment: I meant delta not $\epailon '' $ !

Comment: The linearity is used at
\begin{align}
\Vert F_u\left(u,v+l\right)h -F_u\left(u,v\right)h  \Vert &=\Vert \left(F_u\left(u,v+l\right)-F_u\left(u,v\right)\right)h  \Vert  \\ &\leq \Vert F_u\left(u,v+l\right) -F_u\left(u,v\right)\Vert \Vert h  \Vert
\end{align}

Comment: in the proof, $\delta$ is dependent on both $h$ and $l$

Comment: we can take minimum of $\delta$'s

Comment: $F_u (u,v)$ is not necessarily continuous w.r.t  $v$ , even when $u$ is fixed.

Comment: moreover you may not take min or inf over $\delta$ s since the number of $l$s is infinite.

Comment: we assume that the partial derivative is continuous !